# React context provider is not passing value even for simplest form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am stuck with React context, I have been trying with it but didn't work.

So I created a very simple project on Codesandbox to figure out why it is not working.
My project only has `App.js` and `CategoriesContext.js`, that is it.

Once I add provider project doesn't even show this h2.
I tried also it as a function with {() => elements here} but didn't work too.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { CategoriesProvider } from "../src/Context/CategoriesContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CategoriesProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello Hoooooks</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </CategoriesProvider>
  );
}
```

and CategoriesContext.js

```
import React from "react";

export const CategoriesContext = React.createContext();

export const CategoriesProvider = props => {
  return (
    <CategoriesContext.Provider value={"Hello"}>
      {props.chilren}
    </CategoriesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And here is a link for the simple project
https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-example-8bkmk?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `props.children`, currently you rendering `props.chilren` which is `undefined`:

```
export const CategoriesProvider = props => {
  return (
    <CategoriesContext.Provider value={"Hello"}>
      {props.children}
    </CategoriesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```